# "Error: command failed with exit status 2" when installing Sherlock in Conda, how to resolve?

Tags: python, anaconda

So I'm trying to install Sherlock with Anaconda. I built my environment with Python 3.6.1 and downloaded Microsoft Visual Build Tools C++ 14.0, but now I'm getting the error: `command failed with exit status 2` when it tries to build the wheel for HMpTy (setup.py).

[image: screenshot]

Do I need to reinstall Microsoft Visual Build Tools? Or is there another way to fix this issue?

Comment: It would help if you showed us the command you used, plus the entire error.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the error message directly, not as an image.

Comment: Please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/.